# How Does Github issue ID generate?

Tags: database

I am developing a bug tracing system like Github issue. When I was designing the database table using PostgreSQL, I came across a problem:

How Does Github issue ID generate?

I have thought some possible solutions:

## 1. Create a table for each repo.

This solution is awesome when generate Id by Using PostgreSQL SERIAL To Create Auto-increment Column.

However, when repo Grows up, There will be too many tables to manage.

## 2. Sort

Select all the issues for a repo, then sort them by ID. In this way, we will have a real ID and a logic ID.

This solution can store all issues in one table. But selecting all issues every time is not good.

## How can I do that?

Comment: Couldn't you just keep track of the last issued ID number?

Comment: Maybe I can track the count of issues for every repo when create an issue.